# Symfony - Validation on multiple elements in Collection form

Tags: php, forms, symfony, entity

So, I have a form which has a collection and the user can add new items to this collection. My entity in this collection has an id and an integer. I want to validate that the user cannot add a item after another that has a lower integer than the first one.

For exemple, the form is empty, the user adds a record to the collection by clicking on the Add button. He enters 100 in the input field and adds another record and enters 50 in the input field. When he tries to submit I want the second record to have an error because 50 is lower than 100 but he added it after in the list.

Here are my FormTypes and Entites

```
class ItemType extends AbstractType
{    
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {        
        $builder->add('value');
    }
}

class ItemCollectionType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {   
        $builder->add('items', 'collection', array(
            'type' => new ItemType(),
            'allow_add'    => true,
            'allow_delete' => true,
            'by_reference' => false,
            'label' => false,
        ));

        $builder->add('save');
    }
}

class Item
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $value;
}

class List
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Item", cascade={"persist"})
     * @Assert\Valid
     **/
    private $items;
}
```

I think I could do the validation in the Controller but I would like to do it in my Entity and using a Validation or a custom Validation.

** **EDIT** **

I can also do what DonCallisto suggested but I am trying to get error on the specific row that is in problem not just on the global class like he suggested.

I can't find how to add the propertyPath to the item in problem, I have tried to use the following code but it seems like it's still binding the error on the class rather than on the item itself like I would like.

```
$context->addViolationAt(
    $context->getPropertyPath().'.items.data.value',
    'Your violation message'
);
```

It also doesn't take in consideration the current element.

The following code is not working either. Here I'm hardcoding the key of the array just for the purpose of testing.

```
$context->addViolationAt(
    $context->getPropertyPath().'.items[0].data.value',
    'Your violation message'
);
```

Can anyone tell me how to correctly set up a path to access a child's value in a collection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer to my question, I used part of DonCallisto's answer and I moved the code from the `List` Entity to `Item` and in a validator that I am calling as a `CLASS_CONSTRAINT` on my `Item` Entity.

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintValidator;

/**
 * @Annotation
 */
class ItemsOrderedValidator extends ConstraintValidator  {

    public function validate($value, Constraint $constraint) {
        foreach ($value->getList()->getItems() as $item) {
            $currentValue = $item->getValue();

            if (isset($prevValue) && $prevValue >= $currentValue && $value === $item) {
                $this->context->buildViolation($constraint->message)
                    ->atPath('value')
                    ->addViolation();
            }
            $prevValue = $currentValue;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: wow finally found a solution, all i needed was `->atPath('value')` part in my code, spent 2 days going crazy over it :)

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly your question, you could modify your List entity as follows

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\ExecutionContext;

/**
 * //Whatever you have here to declare this as an entity
 * @Assert\Callback(methods={"areItemsOrdered"})
 */
class List
{
  /**
   * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Item", cascade={"persist"})
   * @Assert\Valid
   **/
   private $items;
    
   //whatever methods you have here

   public function areItemsOrdered(ExecutionContext $context)
   {
     foreach ($this->items as $item) {
       $current_value = $item->getValue();
       
       if (!isset($prev_value)) {
         $prev_value = $current_value;
        } else { 
          if ($prev_value > $current_value) {
            $context->addViolation('Your violation message');
          }
        }
     }
   }
}
```

For more information about entity callback methods: http://symfony.com/doc/2.3/reference/constraints/Callback.html

For more information about ExecutionContext: http://api.symfony.com/2.4/Symfony/Component/Validator/ExecutionContextInterface.html

### BTW

Is a correct behaviour to inform user about error? I mean, could you not sort added items yourself?
If so, please update your answer and I will be happy to update my code for this purpose.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I will test it in a couple of minutes. To answer your question, no I cannot sort the items myself because this is part of bigger problem, I tried to simplicify it before asking, and it has to be a mistake from the user if the items are not sorted properly.

Comment: Would it be possible to add the validation on the record that is incorrect and not on the global class that is containing the records? The context element doesn't seem to have access to the child's context.

Comment: @Johnny Dew you nave to use addViolationAdd() method. Please take a look to link I have provided.

Comment: Could you be a little more specific because it seems that addViolationAdd() offers the possibility to add a violation on a element of the current class you are validating. But I would like to add a validation on the second element of the item list. The field in default will have a red background. If I keep the error on the class it will not be possible to highlight the exact problem to the user.

Comment: @Johnny Dew: could you show US your form? Maybe I can't get the problemi. Btw addViolationAt() could help you to add an error to a specific field so, if your "ma in" form have item lists in itself, you could sue that method without Andy troubles

Comment: Ok, but how would I access the field in the list? I cannot do something like this `$context->addViolationAt($item->getValue(),'Your violation message');` and if I do something like this `$context->addViolationAt('value','Your violation message');` it won't be specific to the current item

Comment: @Johnny Dew You should use entity property name. If you want to access the form collection field you should implement this validation inside the embedded form. I can't help you anymore than this but trust me, is the right way (I've done a lot of time before)

Comment: If I implement the validation inside the Item Entity I will not be able the compare it with the previous item.

Comment: @Johnny Dew You can try with 'error_bubbling' => false into your main form builder (put it into embedded/collection form's option, into add() method.